# How to store json in a file and read from it?

Tags: json, shell

How to store the return value a command which will be json into some file and extract values from it using shell script?

Comment: to store an output to file use command > file.json

Comment: For the rest we have to know more details I suppose: which command, what to do with values etc. but you can start from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools